# How should i expect exponential decay to work in this case? (Adam optimizer)

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, adam

I was facing high learning rate issues i.e., validation loss started to diverge after 9-13 epochs. In order mitigate that i have significantly reduced the learning rate from 4e-3 to 4e-4 and configured a exponential decay scheduler with the settings below:

```py
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=4e-4,
    decay_steps=1620,  # where 1620 = step_size (180) * num_epochs (9)
    decay_rate=0.5)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
```

Despite that, after 9 epochs the loss converged, which from my perspective still a signal from the necessity of reducing the learning rate even more. My concern is, knowing that after 9 epochs the model's loss would increase i have placed a scheduler to reduce lr and prevent it from doing so. In this case how should i expect that the loss should behaved and if a high learning rate was a problem why the decay didn't prevented the loss from converging since after every 9 epochs the lr was reduced (trained for a total of 30 epochs). **Am i configuring something wrong or the decay rate was simply not enough?** **When a model starts to converge it is possible to prevent it from keep going?**

[image: before] [image: after]

**Before /  after**

Comment: Why do you believe that the validation loss should continue to decrease? It seems plausible that perhaps this particular model has fit the data "as well as it can."

Comment: good question, i ran a few epochs with a reduced lr (1e-4) and the loss kept diminishing but due to the exponential decay it was a little shy. I'm testing  1e-4 without exp decay to see what happens.